# change size of card-view in materializecss

Tags: css, user-interface, web, materialize

I am using materializecss framework  , I want to know that how I can change the size of the components in that , For example I am using hoverable card view and I want to resize its width to 400px , Here's the code I was using

```
<div class="card hoverable small">
          <div class="card-image">
            <img src="images/sample-1.jpg">
            <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
          </div>
          <div class="card-content">
            <p>This is simple card.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-action">
            <a href="#">This is a link</a>
          </div>
    </div>
```

`

Comment: just add `card{width:400px;}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want the `card` to have `400px` width in whole of your project than

**Add**

```
.card {
 width:400px;
}
```

**OR**

If you want the `card` to have `400px` width only if you want to use whenever you want than give a class to the `card` like i have given in the snippet and add the css

```
.card-small {
     width:400px;
    }
```

Check the snippet..

```css
.card-small {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.1/css/materialize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="card hoverable small card-small">
  <div class="card-image">
    <img src="images/sample-1.jpg">
    <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
  </div>
  <div class="card-content">
    <p>This is simple card.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="card-action">
    <a href="#">This is a link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

it is a advisable that in responsive layout you should use percentage instead of pixels but if you want to use width :400px you can use following code.

just see the screen resolution at which you want the width of card to be 400px and put that resolution in media query as shown below with your card width class.

in this example i have shown initial width is 800px then when my resolution comes to 767px media query will change the width to 400px and it will remain till resolution is 480 px then again on 480 it will change the width from 400 to 100px as written in media query.

```css
.card { width:800px;}



@media only screen
and (max-width : 480px) {
.card { width:100px;}
}


@media only screen
and (max-width : 767px) {
.card { width:400px;}
}
```

Comment: how can i use percentage? instead of pixels , like in android have density-pixels dp is there something like that in this which is independent of screen resolution ?

Comment: how do you want your card to be will its width will change with the changing resolution

Comment: yep like in smaller screens, I want my card to adjust accordingly to display size